# Update-browser.org auto redirect if browser unsupported.

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've tried various auto redirecting functions to see if I couldn't get it to trigger if the browser version is not supported. What we want to do is redirect the user instead of giving them a popup. We are using browser-update.org

```
 <script>
    var $buoop = {
        vs: {i:6,f:2,o:9.63,s:2,c:10},  // browser versions to notify
        reminder: 0,                   // atfer how many hours should the message reappear
                                        // 0 = show all the time
        reminderClosed: 0,            // if the u,ser closes message it reappears after x hours
        onshow: function(infos){},      // callback function after the bar has appeared
        onclick: function(infos){},     // callback function if bar was clicked
        onclose: function(infos){},     //

        l: false,                       // set a language for the message, e.g. "en"
                                        // overrides the default detection
        test: true,                    // true = always show the bar (for testing)
        text: "test me now what",                       // custom notification html text
                                        // Optionally include up to two placeholders "%s" which will be replaced with the browser version and contents of the link tag. Example: "Your browser (%s) is old.  Please <a%s>update</a>"
        text_xx: "",                    // custom notification text for language "xx"
                                        // e.g. text_de for german and text_it for italian
        newwindow: true,                // open link in new window/tab
        url: 'http://google.com',                       // the url to go to after clicking the notification
        show: function(){
            console.log('show fired')
            window.location = "http://google.com"
        }
    };
    function $buo_f(){
        var e = document.createElement("script");
        e.src = "//browser-update.org/update.min.js";
        document.body.appendChild(e);
    };
    try {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", $buo_f,false)}
    catch(e){window.attachEvent("onload", $buo_f)}
</script>
```

//

I looked for documentation on how to do this and couldn't find  anything. If anyone knows how this system works to overide the click functionality and automatically bypass the popup and take the user to another page, that would be great.

If you put this script into a basic html page it should work immediately. I've turned test:true on so it can be tested in any browser.

Hopefully by creating this post it will solve this same problem for someone else.

Thanks all,

Brandon

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work.
`code`
  function redirect() {                       
      var thing = $('p:contains("test")').text
          if(thing) {                         
              $(location).attr('href',"http://
               } }                            
  redirect();//Call your function
`code`

Comment: I also tried this but it didn't work because it automatically redirected every time.

  <script>
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("buorg")) {
            window.location.href = "redirectpage.html";
        }
    </script>

It redirects even if test is set to false.